# Naming a Package in Java after an e-mail address, when said e-mail address contains periods before the "@" symbol

Tags: java, naming-conventions, package

As I'm sure we all know, one can name packages for their Java products by purchasing a domain name like "somedomain.org", in which case the packages would follow the "org.somedomain.packagename" pattern (relevant source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).

For those who don't have a domain name, however, e-mail addresses are presented as an alternative. For instance, someone whose name is John Bob Doe might have created a GMail account such as "john_bob_doe@gmail.com", and thus would name their packages like so: "com.gmail.john_bob_doe" and "com.gmail.jon_bob_doe.someinnerpackage"

This is all fine and dandy, but what would happen if his e-mail address were "john-bob-doe@gmail.com"? Well, according to the link above, in the presence of a hyphenated name, we could replace the hyphens with underscores. Thus, again: "com.gmail.john_bob_doe" and "com.gmail.jon_bob_doe.someinnerpackage".

Now here's the "real" question: what would happen if his e-mail address were "john.bob.doe@gmail.com"? Should the package naming be "com.gmail.john.bob.doe" then? Or maybe "com.gmail.doe.bob.john"? Basically, the question is: how should one name their packages when, before the "@" symbol, their e-mail address contains periods?

**Reasoning:** I have an e-mail address like that, and I'd like to use it for naming my project's packages.

Comment: How much does it matter?  There's probably not a fixed convention in that case, so do whatever you want.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm not sure exactly how much it matters, but judging from Nathaniel Ford's answer below, I suppose it doesn't matter much. "Doing whatever you want", to me, doesn't sound like an appropriate strategy, but considering that, like you said, "there's not a fixed convention in that case", I see your point.

Answer (score 4):

Please note that naming conventions of Java packages are just that; conventions. You can name them whatever you want. The only thing that is enforced is that a `.` delineates a subdirectory in the filesystem where the compiler looks for the source.

Also note that with gmail, at least, the `.` is ignored in the email. Therefore `myname@gmail.com` and `my.name@gmail.com` are equivalent. Because they are equivalent, `com.gmail.myname` would be an appropriate package name tied to such an email address.

The reason for using domain names/email addresses is that they are a convenient way to (probably) avoid namespace collisions for packages. However, with modern refactoring technology available in your local IDE, this should not be a blocker for progress. Choose a non-top-level-domain prefix and name your program or library whatever you want `rogue.my.awesome.java.program`.

Finally, note that naming your package something like `com.google.myname` implies that google developed the package. Most programmers, for this reason, put some amount of work into establishing some screen name or shortening of their actual name as an online presence so that they can use that as a prefix for this and similar projects: `myname.awesome.java.program`. This satisfies an elegant secondary concern of naming: knowing who to contact if, upon coming across the source, you have questions.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single right way to do this.

What you need to bear in mind is the purpose of this convention / guidance on package name formation ... which is:

- to minimize the risk of accidental package name collisions between Java code-bases developed independently of each other, and
- to convey some information about who or what "owns" the namespace you are creating.

From this perspective `com.gmail.john.bob.doe` or `com.gmail.doe.bob.john` work equally well to minimize the collision risk, and there is minimal risk that intelligent people will think that `com.gmail` (i.e. Google) owns the namespace.

---

Use of underscores violates the general Java identifier naming conventions ... and I'd recommend against that